# Word to describe false confidence in another person

Tags: single-word-requests

As an example: Alice and Bob participated in a trust fall. As Bob falls, Alice fails to catch him (and Bob therefore falls straight to the ground)

Comment: Misplaced trust. Literally.

Comment: Did Alice try and fail, perhaps because she was not strong enough, or not try? Big difference.

Comment: The confidence was real, just misguided.

Comment: Are you limiting this to misguided/misplaced confidence in another's capabilities? Excluding deliberate betrayal?

Comment: There are shades of meaning around whether the confidence was deliberately solicited with the intention of being betrayed, or whether it occurred without having a proper cause/reason. But Edwin Ashworth's answer has most of the options.

Answer (score 1):

The person taking the unwise step of faith displays **credulousness**.

> **credulousness** [noun]
>
> the tendency to believe too readily and therefore to be easily
> deceived

[[Vocabulary.com]

synonyms **gullibility**, **naiveness** / **naivety**